# Php subtract time saved in session with current time

Tags: php, session, datetime, yii

i am using jquery countdown timer but the problem is that timer start from value set every time on page refresh . I want to get time on first time and Save in PHP Session and subtract second time from frist time and update session etc. In Simple Word i want to create php countdown timer run only 50 using php

here is my controller code

```
public function actionViewtimer($id) {
    $session = Yii::app()->session;
    $this->layout = 'countdownlayout';
    if (empty($session['countdowntime'])) {
        $orderTime = microtime(true); #when user first time enter timer start from 50 mins
        $session->add('countdowntime', array($orderTime));   //replace this line
    } else {
        $time_end = microtime(true);
        $orderTime = $time_end - $time_start;
        unset($session['countdowntime']);//unset old session
        $session->add('countdowntime', array($orderTime));   //when user enter second  
    }

    $getMinutes = $getMinutes_from_orderTime ; #please tell me how  we extact minutes and pass them to view

    $session->add('timersession', array($rand));   
    $this->render('viewtimerpage', array(
        'getMinutes' => $getMinutes
    ));
}
```

here is my jquery code

```
 <script>
 $(function() {
     $('#xlarge').countdowntimer({
          minutes: 50<?php echo $getMinutes; ?>,
          size: "lg",
          timeUp: timeisUp
     });
 });

 function timeisUp() {
     alert('Time Complete');
     return false;
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: I am not sure about what your problem is. Can you explain better what should start and what should stop the timer?

Comment: I'm not sure about what you really try to do as @HenriqueBarcelos said. But flash data may help you : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-sessions-cookies.html#flash-data

Comment: yes i am using HenriqueBarcelos , when i land on timer page , timer start from 50 second , suppose i close the browser and open timer page again after 15 second , it start from 35 seconds 50-15=35

Comment: I think he is trying to have a persistent countdown timer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I've not used Yii so this example will be in plain PHP.

```
session_start();

if(!isset($_POST['counter']) || !is_array($_POST['counter')) {
    $duration = 50;
    $counter = array(
        'start_time' => new DateTime()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'end_time' => new DateTime()->modify("+{$duration} minute")->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'duration' => $duration
    );

    $_SESSION['counter'] = $counter;
}
$counter = $_POST['counter'];

$now = new DateTime();
$end_time = new DateTime($counter['end_time']);
$time_left = $end_time->getTimestamp() - $now->getTimestamp();

echo "{$time_left} seconds left";
```

This should be simple enough to convert, and you can easily convert seconds to minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Don't destroy the session variable. Just set it the first time when its empty and then plug that value always into your countdown timer.

Inside you action

```
$session = Yii::app()->session;
$this->layout = 'countdownlayout';
if (empty($session['countdowntime'])) {
    $date = new DateTime();
    $date->modify('+50 minutes'); // Add 50 minutes to current time
    $session['countdowntime'] = $date->format('Y/m/d H:i:s'); // Store date in session
} 
$this->render('viewtimerpage', array(
    'countdowntime' => $session['countdowntime'];
));
```

jQuery Code

```
$(function() {
    $('#xlarge').countdowntimer({
        dateAndTime : "<?php echo $countdowntime; ?>",
        size: "lg",
        timeUp: timeisUp
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to show difference between 2 dates. Default value = 50 minutes(value for session if user first time opened page). If user refresh page after 10 minutes in view must show difference(40). It will be something like that:

```
public function actionViewtimer($id) {
        $this->layout = 'countdownlayout';
        /** @var CHttpSession $session */
        $session = Yii::app()->session;
        $minutes = 50; //default value for minutes

        if (!$session->offsetExists('countdowntime')) {
            $session->add('countdowntime', new DateTime()); //set value to session
        } else {
            $timeEnd = new DateTime();
            /** @var DateTime $countDownTime */
            $countDownTime = $session->get('countdowntime');
            $interval = $countDownTime->diff($timeEnd);
            $countMinutes = $interval->days * 24 * 60;

            $countMinutes += $interval->h * 60;
            $countMinutes += $interval->i;
            $minutes -= $countMinutes;

            $session->add('countdowntime', $timeEnd);   //refresh value
        }

//        $session->add('timersession', array($rand)); don't know for what is it
        $this->render('viewtimerpage', array(
            'getMinutes' => $minutes
        ));
}
```

And js:

```
<script>
 $(function() {
     $('#xlarge').countdowntimer({
          minutes: <?php echo $getMinutes; ?>, //without 50
```

Comment: hi , Danila Ganchar the code is not working ,I have set getMinutes=5 when i refresh page first after 1 minute time it show 4 in getMinutes when i refresh second time it is still showing 4 and if refresh again it show 5 in getMInutes

Comment: Which value must be after 1 minute? 4 is it right? After 2 minutes, the user has updated page. Which value must be? 5-1-2=3 is it right?

Comment: if (!$session->offsetExists('countdowntime')) {
            $timeFirst = strtotime(date("Y-m-d h:i:s", time()));
            $session->add('countdowntime', array($timeFirst)); //set value to session  
        } else {
            $timeFirst = $session['countdowntime'][0];
            $timeSecond = strtotime(date("Y-m-d h:i:s", time()));
            $differenceInSeconds = $timeSecond - $timeFirst;
            $differenceInSeconds = $differenceInSeconds / 60;
            $getminutes = round($differenceInSeconds, 0);
            $minutes = $minutes - $getminutes;
        }